# Could not resolve placeholder 'XXX' in string value "${XXX}"

Tags: spring-boot, environment-variables

In my spring boot example, I'd like to read `environment variables` from my local machine(**Win 7**).

```
@Data
@Component
public class EnvironmentVariableSystemProperties {

  @Value("${java.home}")
  private String javaHome;

  @Value("${DATASTORE.DATASET}")
  private String datastoreDataset;

  @Value("${SPRINGA}")
  private String springConfigName;

}
```

It works well when reading `java.home` and `DATASTORE.DATASET` which have been added in my `OS environment variables` **before**.
I just added a new variable `SPRINGA`. When running spring boot example, I got the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'SPRINGA' in string value "${SPRINGA}".
```

Should I restart up my machine to make the variable work?
I just restarted Eclipse, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Restarting `Eclipse` with the `Restart` in the Menu doesn't work.
Exiting `Eclipse` and Running it again works.
How weird it is!